# jQuery - After deleting and adding new carousel item dynamically, numbers should be re-order

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating Bootstrap carousel slides dynamically with delete options as ***Remove item 1***, ***Remove item 2*** etc... for newly created slides.

For Eg: If I delete **Remove item 3**, Third slide is getting deleted alogn with relevant elements correctly. Same should be applied (numbers re-ordering) while adding new slide

> **While Removing and adding New slide below things should happen**

1. Button text should be re-order as ***Remove item 1***, ***Remove item 2***, ***Remove item 3***, ***Remove item 4*** etc... instead of **1, 2, 4, 5**
2. Carousel item Image text (**Slide 1, Slide 2, Slide 3**) re-ordering
3. Carousel indicator **data-slide-to** number re-ordering

[image]

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('pause'); 
});

var count=1;
$("#addSlide").click(function(){
  var carouselIndicators="<li id='ciIndicator"+count+"' data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='"+count+"'></li>";
  var carouselItem="<div id='ciItem"+count+"' class='item'><img src='http://placehold.it/400x200&text=Slide "+count+"' alt='' /></div>";
  var removeItem="<button id='ciBtnRemove"+count+"' onclick=foo('"+count+"')>Remove slide "+count+"</button>";
  $("ol.carousel-indicators").append(carouselIndicators);
  $(".carousel-inner").append(carouselItem);
  $("#removeItemContainer").append(removeItem);
  count++;
});

function foo(which){
  $("#ciIndicator"+which).remove();
  $("#ciItem"+which).remove();
  $("#ciBtnRemove"+which).remove();
}
```

```css
.rpCarousel{width:400px;margin:auto;}
.item{position:relative;}
a.remove{position:absolute;top:0;left:100px;z-index:999;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button id="addSlide">Add</button>

<!-- Carousel wrapper -->
<div class="rpCarousel">

  <!-- Carousel holder -->
  <div id='carousel-example-generic' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
      <li class="active" id="ciIndicator0" data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='0'></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- /Indicators -->

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class='carousel-inner'>
      <div id="ciItem0" class='item active'><img src='http://placehold.it/400x200&text=Slide 0' alt='' /></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /Wrapper for slides -->

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide='prev'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span></a>
    <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide='next'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span></a>
    <!-- /Controls -->

  </div>
  <!-- /Carousel holder -->
  
  <div id="removeItemContainer"></div>

</div>
<!-- /Carousel wrapper -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps.

1. Add class `remove_btn` to button
2. Add function to resetCounter()
3. Call function resetCounter() after removing slide

```js
$(window).load(function() {
      $('#carousel-example-generic').carousel('pause'); 
    });

    var count=1;
    $("#addSlide").click(function(){
      var carouselIndicators="<li id='ciIndicator"+count+"' data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='"+count+"'></li>";
      var carouselItem="<div id='ciItem"+count+"' class='item'><img src='http://placehold.it/400x200&text=Slide "+count+"' alt='' /></div>";
      var removeItem="<button class='remove_btn' id='ciBtnRemove"+count+"' onclick=foo('"+count+"')>Remove slide "+count+"</button>";
      $("ol.carousel-indicators").append(carouselIndicators);
      $(".carousel-inner").append(carouselItem);
      $("#removeItemContainer").append(removeItem);
      count++;
      resetCounter();
    });

   function foo(which){
      $("#ciIndicator"+which).remove();
      $("#ciItem"+which).remove();
      $("#ciBtnRemove"+which).remove();
      resetCounter();
    }

    function resetCounter(){
        $(".remove_btn").each(function(i){
            $(this).text("Remove slide "+ (i+1));
        })
    }
```

```css
.rpCarousel{width:400px;margin:auto;}
    .item{position:re`enter code here`lative;}
    a.remove{position:absolute;top:0;left:100px;z-index:999;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <button id="addSlide">Add</button>

    <!-- Carousel wrapper -->
    <div class="rpCarousel">

      <!-- Carousel holder -->
      <div id='carousel-example-generic' class='carousel slide' data-ride='carousel'>
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class='carousel-indicators'>
          <li class="active" id="ciIndicator0" data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='0'></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- /Indicators -->

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class='carousel-inner'>
          <div id="ciItem0" class='item active'><img src='http://placehold.it/400x200&text=Slide 0' alt='' /></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /Wrapper for slides -->

        <!-- Controls -->
        <a class='left carousel-control' href='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide='prev'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left'></span></a>
        <a class='right carousel-control' href='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide='next'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right'></span></a>
        <!-- /Controls -->

      </div>
      <!-- /Carousel holder -->
      
      <div id="removeItemContainer"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- /Carousel wrapper -->
```

Comment: **@Harpal Singh**, Thanks for the answer. But, can it be done the same (number re-order) for carousel item image text (Slide 1, Slide 2 etc...) and carousel indicator **data-slide-to** number re-ordering please?